# Não consigo terminar a instalação de devtools no R 3.4.0

Tags: r

Estou usando: `R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21) -- "You Stupid Darkness"` no Windows 10.

Ao executar `find_rtools()`, obtenho:

> Erro: execução do comando '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0/bin/x64/R"
>   --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD config CC' teve status 309.

Como proceder?

Obrigado.

Comment: Devtools e Rtools são diferentes. Qual quer instalar?

Comment: Queria instalar Rtools. Repeti a instalação do Rtools com as dlls do cygwin e então consegui completar a configuração. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Se seu R estiver configurado certinho com a rede, acredito que

```
install.packages("devtools")
```

vai já baixar e instalar corretamente. Se não der certo escreve ai que vamos vendo outras alternativas.

Comment: Emanuel, obrigado. Eu havia conseguido instalar o pacote devtools; Rtools é que não havia dado certo. Depois de repetir a instalação do Rtools com as dlls do cygwin, consegui completar a configuração.